# Finding the Vertical Asymptotes

Tags: calculus

Does the graph of y = sin(x-1)/(x^2-1) have a vertical asymptote at x = 1? Justify your answer.

Just looking at the question, you would assume that yes it does because the denominator would be zero if x = 1.

According to Wolfram however, the only asymptote is at x = -1. I can't seem to figure out why or how to get to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{sin(x-1)}{x^2 - 1} = \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{sin(x-1)}{x-1}\cdot \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{1}{x+1} = 1 \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2}$ which is not $\infty$. So you don't have vertical asymptote at $x = 1$.

Comment: This really helped me! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac12\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin(x-1)}{x-1}={1\over 2}$$ The graph approaches 1/2 and does not go off to infinity, so there is no asymptote there.